# How to use C libraries in Vlang for basic statistics

Tags: c, statistics, libraries, vlang

I want to do basic statistics with [Vlang](https://vlang.io/).

Can I use C libraries? For example, Apophenia: http://apophenia.info/

Or IMSL C stat library: https://docs.roguewave.com/en/imsl/c/8.6/pdf/C_Stat_library.pdf

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since the Vlang home page says "C interop without any costs", the answer is presumably "Yes".  You just need to find the right part of the documentation — such as [Calling C functions from V](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/doc/docs.md#calling-c-functions-from-v).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can [call C libraries](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/doc/docs.md#calling-c-functions-from-v) from V.

You need to make the C library's structs, typedefs and functions known to V by defining them in V first - before calling/using them.

For structs you conveniently only need to define the fields you need to use.

Here's some examples:

- [via](https://github.com/prime31/via) 2D game framework wrapping several C libs
- [sokol](https://github.com/vlang/v/tree/master/vlib/sokol) in vlib
- [v-miniaudio](https://github.com/Larpon/v-miniaudio/blob/4726049bca5194b24c26c1048fd13668cc580fd9/miniaudio.c.v) wrapper (disclaimer: my own module)

Generally you can find a lot of C wrapper code in [vlib](https://github.com/vlang/v/tree/master/vlib) itself. (We're working on replacing C with pure V)

Comment: Does Vlang has garbage collection? It is not mentioned on its homepage https://vlang.io/ .

Comment: V's memory management model is inspired by https://aardappel.github.io/lobster/memory_management.html + Rust + falling back to reference counting in the worst-case scenarios. So it's a mix. For C interop, though you have to manage memory yourself. This is done through `unsafe` blocks. Where you explicitly tell the compiler "I've got this".

Comment: This section is now the official info about memory management: https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/doc/docs.md#memory-management